# Send CTR + D to a remote program

Tags: python, fabric

I've been using `fabric` a lot lately and I ran into a situation where a remote program I was interacting with needed me to send the `CTR + D` signal to it.

My feeling is that I need to append some sort of character sequence to the end of the string I'm sending, but I'm not at all sure what that would be.

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL + D` is what is known as a [Control Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). There is an ASCII representation of it which you can explicitly represent as:

- hex: `"\x04"`

So to solve my own problem:

```
cmdstring + "\x04"
```